# В чем существенное отличие хранения изменений файла в git?

Tags: git, git-commit

В чем существенное отличие хранения изменений картинки и к примеру текстового файла в git?

Comment: на верхнем уровне абстрации гит не хранит изменения, поэтому ответ на вопрос - никого. Да, есть ещё pack файлы, но это отдельная история.

Comment: @KoVadim, наоборот, на самом нижнем — уровне хранилища blob-ов.

Comment: файлы -> блобы (архив+метадата) -> pack-file. Внутри packfile уже хранятся изменения.

Answer (score 1):

Git, в отличие от некоторых других VCS не хранит изменения файлов. Он хранит полное содержимое каждого файла. Изменения мы видим только в момент сравнения разных версий этих файлов.

Другой момент в том, что текстовые файлы он может [упаковать](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-Pack-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B) в своей внутренней базе и хранить одинаковые фрагменты только в одном экземпляре. А с двоичными файлами такое невозможно и приходится сохранять каждый раз всю картинку целиком, даже если изменён один байт. Поэтому имеет смысл использовать [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.com/), когда двоичные файлы хранятся в отдельном хранилище, а в репозитории остаются только их метаданные.

Comment: Даже без упаковки сами файлы внутри папки .git\objects уже хранятся в сжатом виде. И это сжатие ориентировано именно на текстовые файлы.